# Azure Data Factory : How to update global parameters from CI/CD pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

Right now, you can include global parameters in ARM template. and that would push to your publish branch in dev environment like this:

```
{
    "environment": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "dev"
    }
}
```

If I release this to prod , how to update the value of the same global variable ?

Can I just use release variable named 'environment' or any other syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends.  If you are using the "new" ci/cd method following something like what is outlined [Azure Data Factory CI-CD made simple: Building and deploying ARM templates with Azure DevOps YAML Pipelines](https://towardsdatascience.com/azure-data-factory-ci-cd-made-simple-building-and-deploying-your-arm-templates-with-azure-devops-30c30595afa5), then you should be able to just set the overrideParameters in your deploy task.  Something like this should work:

```
overrideParameters: '-dataFactory_properties_globalParameters_environment_value "new value here"'
```

Here is an article that goes into more detail on the overrideParameters:  [ADF Release - Set global params during deployment](https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2021/11/adf-snack-set-global-params-during.html)